# Duplicating images in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a method to duplicate images in Carrierwave but receive the error `Validation failed: Image could not download file` when I run it.  It creates a copy of Invoice, then goes through it's associated images, sets them as a remote_image_url and should re-upload them.

I believe it has something to do with the fact that there's AccessKey information at the end of an image url.  Any idea?

```
  def self.duplicate_it(invoice)

    new_invoice = invoice.dup
    new_invoice.save

    if invoice.images.any?
      invoice.images.each do |i|
        temp_image = i.image

        new_image = Image.new(:remote_image_url => temp_image.to_s, :order_id => new_invoice.id)
        new_image.save!
      end
    end 

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
new_invoice = invoice.dup :include => {:lineitems => :images} do |original, kopy|
  kopy.image = original.image if kopy.is_a?(Image)
end
```